If-else condition inside Makefile canned recipe
Using Cygwin v3.5.3, Makefile (GNU Make v4.4.1) on Win11, I have a common canned recipe that is being called from various other targets with different variables.
MYDate = date -u +'$1: %d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'
define cand-recipe =
    $(call MYDate, $(var1))
    $ echo -e "\nIn the canned recipe"
    $ rsync -aqh $(sdir) $(ddir) 2> $(elog)
endef

I call this canned recipe with targets like:
mytarget: var1 := some value
mytarget: sdir := $(SRCDir)
mytarget: ddir := $(DSTDir)
mytarget: elog := $(ERRlogfile)
mytarget:
    $(cand-recipe)

All this is working fine but if I try to add more info with if-else bash statements or process error log then make reports syntax errors or reports error:

*** prerequisites cannot be defined in recipes. Stop.

MYDate = date -u +'$1: %d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'
define cand-recipe =
    $(call MYDate, $(var1))
    $ echo -e "\nIn the canned recipe"
    $ rsync -aqh $(sdir) $(ddir) 2> $(elog)
    $ if [ -s $(elog) ]; then\
        $ $(call MYDate, ERROR:);\
        $ $(eval elogvar := $(file < $(elog)));\
        $ echo -e "\n$(elogvar)\n";\
        $ $(file >> $(elog),$(call MYDate, ERROR:));\
    fi
endef

I'm just trying to read the elog file. If this error log file is NOT empty then I print date on terminal, put the contents of the error log file into a variable, print the contents of error log file on terminal and append the date to the error log file.

I don't understand what the $  prefixes on your command lines are for?  Is that some kind of artifact of your cut and paste?
You can't do this with make functions.  All make variables and functions in the entire recipe are evaluated first before any part of the recipe is invoked.  That means that things like $(file <$(elog)) will be expanded before the recipe is invoked, so clearly the content of the file is not present yet and this can't work.
You should use shell constructs for this, not make constructs.
define cand-recipe =
    $(call MYDate, $(var1))
    echo -e "\nIn the canned recipe"
    rsync -aqh $(sdir) $(ddir) 2> $(elog)
    if [ -s $(elog) ]; then\
        $(call MYDate, ERROR:);\
        cat $(elog);\
        $(call MYDate, ERROR:) >> $(elog);\
    fi
endef


Thanks, I removed Makefile file operations and replaced it with bash operations. I also created a new make target, to be invoked after all processing is finished, in order to print all the error files if they are NOT empty.
